# Notice: Unknown: IMAP protocol error: Could not parse command (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, imap

The following code sets IMAP flags and moves deleted or undeleted emails to their respective folders. Not so much a problem but a curiosity I am having is that when I clear the delete flag (\\Deleted which is actually \Deleted) I get the following Notice "Notice: Unknown: IMAP protocol error: Could not parse command (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0". However everything seems to work just fine the email deleted flag is cleared and the email is moved back to the inbox, nothing unexpected actually occurs.

I have looked online and on StackOverflow for an answer but nothing I have found answers my question. From the PHP docs under `imap_mail_copy()` the notice is reference and the comments say to insure the $message_num is passed a string (eg. `"$msg_num"`, `$msg_num` or `(string) $msg_num`). Nothing has addressed my particular curiosity because like I said the code still does the job perfectly.

As a side question, I post to this script via an ajax with jquery, in the javascript I have to escape the "\" when I pass the flag \Deleted like this: `flag: "\\Deleted"` however when I pass \Seen I pass as follows: `flag: "\Seen"` the escape is not nessesary here. Why?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../constants.php';

$setFlags = [
    '\Seen'     => true,
    '\Answered' => true,
    '\Flagged'  => true,
    '\Deleted'  => true,
    '\Draft'    => true
];

$resetFlags = [
    '\\\\Seen'     => true,
    '\\\\Answered' => true,
    '\\\\Flagged'  => true,
    '\\\\Deleted'  => true,
    '\\\\Draft'    => true
];

$folder = $_POST['folder'];
$flag = $_POST['flag'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$action = isset($_POST['action'])? strtoupper($_POST['action']): '';

if(($imap = imap_open(IMAPSEQUENCE.$folder, IMAPUSER, IMAPPASS)) == false){
    echo 'failed to open email server';
    exit();
}

if($action == 'SET' && $setFlags[$flag]){
    echo imap_setflag_full($imap, $uid, $flag, ST_UID);
    if($flag == '\Deleted'){
        imap_mail_move($imap, "$uid:$uid", '[Gmail]/Trash', CP_UID);
    }
    imap_close($imap);    
    exit();
} elseif($action == 'RESET' && $resetFlags[$flag]){
    echo imap_clearflag_full($imap, $uid, $flag, ST_UID);
    if($flag == '\\\\Deleted'){
        echo imap_mail_move($imap, "$uid:$uid", 'INBOX', CP_UID);
    }
    imap_close($imap);    
    exit();     
}

echo '<strong style="color: red;">Email action failed';
imap_close($imap);    
exit();
?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Javascript, jQuery, and AJAX?

Comment: In PHP, escape sequences are only processed inside double quotes, not single quotes. That's why you don't have to double the backslash.